# Not able to resize hard disk partition

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, hard-drive

While installing ubuntu 18.04 I didn't partition my hard disk. Now my hard disk is a single partition /dev/sda2. I have tried to resize this partition but i'm getting the error saying system busy.

Is there any way I can partition my hard disk without losing data?

Comment: While installing Ubuntu have you selected "Erase Disk and Install" option? Or something else option? It is possible if you boot with live session. Taking backup is highly recommended when you do this. Use GParted from live session to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't resize a partition while it is mounted. To get around this you can boot from a Live usb, then open a tool like gparted to resize the partition

Comment: could you provide me procedure for that.. thanks

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/18525/383204